# How to record screen, with both internal sound and microphone sound?

Tags: screencast, recordmydesktop, desktop-recording

I'm trying to capture my screen, including the audio that's going to the speakers and the audio going into my microphone. So far no luck.

RecordMyDesktop seems to be the most recommended option for screen recording. I am able to record the screen together with one audio option but not both. Installed `pavucontrol`, which allows me to adjust the stream source. If I choose "Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo", it records the microphone. If I choose "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo", it records what's happening on the screen. But I can't find an option for both.

Searching here, I found a suggestion to use this command:
`pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1`
It redirects the microphone into the speakers, so recording the speakers actually does record both. But this also means I have my own voice blaring out of the speakers all the time, which is highly distracting with headphones and even creates a feedback loop without headphones.

Are there any other solutions? Is there really no user-friendly option for recording the screen together with the microphone?

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/weekend-project-record-skype-calls-and-other-apps-linux), especially the chapters on "Full-Duplex-Recording" and "The CLI Approach".